# Why was Who Framed Roger Rabbit migrated?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

I was wondering if we could find out why https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/who-framed-roger-rabbit was migrated?

There's no comment indicating why it was migrated that I can see, questions on "plot, character or setting explanations" for SFF works are on-topic according to the FAQ and Gilles also commented on the question that he's not sure why it was shifted.

There are plenty of other questions on SFF works that don't involve the SFF elements on this site - should these be migrated too, or was this just a jumping of the gun?

Comment: As a matter of policy (applicable to all Stack Exchange), we do not migrate on-topic questions (we may migrate *borderline* questions to a site where they are strongly on-topic) except sometimes when they have been unanswered for a while (which suggests they have reached the wrong audience). See also [How do we handle conflicts with the Literature and Movies sites?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/626) : the existence of a movie site does not make questions about SF movies somehow off-topic here. I don't know why this question was migrated: it seems perfectly on-topic to me.

Comment: Additional note: Since I used the original title of the film as the question-title, this *could* be a potential Google magnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably been too long since I've seen it, but I guess I just didn't consider Roger Rabbit to be science fiction or fantasy, thus my decision to migrate it. Also, it had briefly been discussed in chat, and a flag made, which to me meant I wasn't the only one with doubts as to it's science fiction/fantasy aspects. After a bit more work, I'd argue that it is borderline, and a much better fit on the movies site. But maybe that's just because I haven't seen Roger Rabbit for a long time...

Comment: I would tend towards agreeing with migrating it for these reasons, since at a glance it looks more like plain "fiction" rather than sci-fi or fantasy to me.  However, I'm probably an even worse judge since I haven't even seen the movie ;)

Comment: @Izkata What  definition of fantasy would reject cartoons of the Tom & Jerry style (which Who Framed... fits)? Exactly what non-fantastical reality allows individuals to run out into mid air until they notice there is no ground etc.? And then consider the premise of a "normal" world alongside the cartoon world with easy movement between them (very much a theme of many fantasies)?

Comment: @Richard Aha, movement between the two is a good point.  I tend towards thinking of the usage of animation as a stylistic choice, rather than a plot device/indication of the world itself.

Comment: We tend to not include childrens works, unless they are very much intended as SFF, even if they might have some elements that make them such. See http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/683/98

Comment: I agree.  The genre of the movie is, at best, a murder mystery.  Sci-fi/fantasy elements doesn't necessarily mean something is sci-fi/fantasy (i'll get flamed for this, but Star Wars isn't sci-fi).

Answer (score 1):

I guess I don't agree that migration is a negative thing - the point of SE questions is to seek good answers. If you're primarily looking for an answer to a question, then it shouldn't matter if the question is migrated to another place that's likely to give you a good answer.

Roger Rabbit, while it has fantastical elements, is primarily known as a hugely popular movie. Movies.SE is therefore an excellent place to find people who might provide good answers.

Now, if it had been migrated to RabbitHusbandry.SE, that might be an issue. ;) But Movies.SE seems like a good choice.

Comment: This case is slighty funny using that rule of thumb because it did have two very good answers before it got migrated.